# Align navbar with my logo

Tags: html, css, navigation, styles, navbar

I'm trying to align my navbar vertically so that it lays in the center next to my logo. I tried just adding some margin-top to the bar div element and that works, but it aligns it differently on different screens, I need something consistent. I've been stumped on this for a while, and if anyone can help that'd be great. Also if any of my CSS or HTML is bad practice let me know as well! Thank you

[Here is what it looks like as of right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgYkr.png)

```css
.row {
  height: 20%;
}

.logo {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.bar {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 600px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bar-auth {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 300px;
}

.icon {
  padding: 15px;
}

.icon-auth {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="{{ url('index') }}"><img src={{ URL::asset( 'images/logo_opt.png')}} alt="Logo" class="logo"></a>
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="icon icon-1"><a href="{{ url('index') }}">Home</a </div>
                <div class="icon dropdown"><a href="{{ url('whatsnew') }}">What's New</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="{{ url('whatsnew') }}">Calendar</a>
        <a href="{{ url('whatsnew') }}">Events</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon icon-3"><a href="{{ url('legacy') }}">Legacy</a></div>
    <div class="icon icon-3"><a href="{{ url('getinvolved') }}">Get Involved</a></div>
    <div class="icon icon-3"><a href="{{ url('gallery') }}">Gallery</a></div>
    <div class="icon icon-3"><a href="{{ url('contact') }}">Contact</a></div>
    <!-- Authentication Links -->
  </div>

  <div class="bar-auth">
    @if (Auth::guest())
    <div class="icon-auth"><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></div>
    <div class="icon-auth"><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></div>
    @else
    <div class="icon-auth"><a href="#">{{"Welcome, " . Auth::user()->first_name }}</a></div>
    <div class="icon-auth">
      <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                               document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                            Logout
                        </a>
      <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
      </form>
    </div>
    @endif
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: use flexbox https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/YqaKYR

Comment: can you show a pic of how you wanted it to be ?

Comment: @AdernNerk Well, this is how it looks right now, https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgYkr.png, and I just want the nav items dropped down so it lines up in the center next to the logo

Comment: Give some line height to parent nav div and add vertical-align : middle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` to parent of logo and navbar and set `align-items` to `center` to achieve your result

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Note: the `.parent` class here is the parent of logo and navbar. this is just for example. use your class instead.
remove the margin that you have given to set vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-height` to **align** your **navbar**. You can use like :

```
.bar{
    line-height:20%;
}
```